# How do I group by where 1 field value differs

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm new to MySQL, tried looking for the soluion for my problem but didn't quit find it or simply don't understand how to use the given solutions, so I hope you can help me.

I have 1 MySQL database table containing the following information.
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiBqD.png)

```
Data   Attributename  Objectname    Location
--------------------------------------------
car    name           car           front
car    name           car           back
car    type           car           MPV
door   name           car           left
```

I want my query to give me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N17X6.png) result? the comma can also be a newline char.

```
Data   Attributename  Objectname    Location
------------------------------------------------
car    name           car           front, back
car    type           car           MPV
door   name           car           left
```

So basically how can I query this table to group by this result (sorry for the bad English)
Or do i need to solve this in my code?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Read up on [Group_Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following for comma:

```
SELECT Data,Attributename,Objectname, GROUP_CONCAT(Location SEPARATOR ',') AS Location
FROM table GROUP BY Data,Attributename,Objectname;
```

Try following for newline:

```
SELECT Data,Attributename,Objectname, GROUP_CONCAT(Location SEPARATOR '\n') AS Location
FROM table GROUP BY Data,Attributename,Objectname;
```

You can also concat for unique value only:

```
SELECT Data,Attributename,Objectname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Location SEPARATOR '\n') AS Location
FROM table GROUP BY Data,Attributename,Objectname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GROUP_CONCAT` in select and `GROUP_BY`

```
Select Data,Attributename,Objectname,GROUP_CONCAT(Location) As Location 
From table 
Group by Data,Attributename,Objectname
```

Comment: Group by all non-aggregated fields.  not just 1 of them.  You don't know enough about the data to not.

Comment: @xQbert in his result data group by Attributename

Comment: @Siva If you just group by Attributename, will return two rows only

Comment: at a minium it would need to be data, attributeName.  mySQL's extended group by has been disabled by default in 5.7+ because the feature gets misused so often.  Other RDBMS don't support the extended group by; and would error.  Best teach the basics first then let people learn about the extended group by.  It's best to always group by all non-aggregated fields; and performance tune the extended group by if needed.

Comment: @xQbert and "R.yan" ya you are correct, thanks for yours comments.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and explanation, this helps me a lot